# Delete rows in list based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the following list using `list(itertools.permutations(['D1','O2','D2'],r=3))`

```
[('D1', 'O2', 'D2'),
 ('D1', 'D2', 'O2'),
 ('O2', 'D1', 'D2'),
 ('O2', 'D2', 'D1'),
 ('D2', 'D1', 'O2'),
 ('D2', 'O2', 'D1')]
```

and want to remove the rows where D2 comes before O2 (meaning row 2, 5 and 6 should be removed).

How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you write a function that takes a single tuple and returns whether the condition is true:

```
def d2_before_o2(X):
    # ('D1', 'O2', 'D2')
    d2_seen = False
    o2_seen = False
    for i in X:
        ... fill this in
```

Then you can use a list comprehension

```
L = [('D1', 'O2', 'D2'), ('D1', 'D2', 'O2'),.......]
L = [X for X in L if d2_before_o2(X)]
```

Comment: That last line is not Python :)

Comment: haha sorry, fixed mixing languages too much

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. Here is a very simple one and easy to understand:

```py
arr = [('D1', 'O2', 'D2'),
       ('D1', 'D2', 'O2'),
       ('O2', 'D1', 'D2'),
       ('O2', 'D2', 'D1'),
       ('D2', 'D1', 'O2'),
       ('D2', 'O2', 'D1')]
newArr = []

for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i].index('D2') >= arr[i].index('O2'):
        newArr.append(arr[i])
print(newArr)

# [('D1', 'O2', 'D2'), ('O2', 'D1', 'D2'), ('O2', 'D2', 'D1')]
```

I have written a new list called `newArr` and it appends the indices of the original list that fulfill the condition you need.

The new list only returns what you need. The original list is never changed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to just use `list.index`

```
perms = [p for p in perms if p.index("D2") > p.index("O2")]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using `list.index` is that the latter only returns the index of the *first* occurrence of the target element. Therefore, input like `l=('O2', 'D2', 'O2')` will fail when using `list.index`, since `l.index('O2')` is `0`, while `l.index('D2')` is `1`, so a basic index comparison would erroneously validate this list. Instead, compare the minimum and maximum indices of `O2` and `D2` using `enumerate`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def is_valid(d):
   _d = defaultdict(list)
   for i, a in enumerate(d):
      _d[a].append(i)
   return min(_d['D2']) > max(_d['O2'])

data = [('D1', 'O2', 'D2'), ('D1', 'D2', 'O2'), ('O2', 'D1', 'D2'), ('O2', 'D2', 'D1'), ('D2', 'D1', 'O2'), ('D2', 'O2', 'D1'), ('O2', 'D2', 'O2')]
result = [(i, is_valid(i)) for i in data]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(('D1', 'O2', 'D2'), True), 
 (('D1', 'D2', 'O2'), False), 
 (('O2', 'D1', 'D2'), True), 
 (('O2', 'D2', 'D1'), True), 
 (('D2', 'D1', 'O2'), False), 
 (('D2', 'O2', 'D1'), False), 
 (('O2', 'D2', 'O2'), False)]
```

To filter `data`:

```
result = [i for i in data if is_valid(i)]
```

Output:

```
[('D1', 'O2', 'D2'), ('O2', 'D1', 'D2'), ('O2', 'D2', 'D1')]
```